# Extract image URL in a string (RSS with syndicationfeed)

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-7, rss

i have this :

`<img src="http://MyUrl.JPG.jpg" width="180" ...`

and i need this :

http://MyUrl.JPG.jpg

thank

Comment: A very simillar thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965893/regular-expression-to-extract-the-url-out-of-the-anchor-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete solution with regex :

```
string source ="<img src=\"http://MyUrl.JPG.jpg\"";
var reg = new Regex("src=(?:\"|\')?(?<imgSrc>[^>]*[^/].(?:jpg|bmp|gif|png))(?:\"|\')?");
var match=reg.Match(source);
if(match.Success)
{
  var encod = match.Groups["imgSrc"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If that's really *all* you have you *might* get away with a regular expression, like

```
src="([^"]+)
```

However, you can't and shouldn't try to parse HTML in general with regular expressions. [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Instead use an HTML parser like [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). I don't know if it's available for WP7, though.

Comment: The HAP does work with WP7. Get it from source http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets